# Is the period of an irreducible Markov Chain the same for all states?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, markov-chains, markov-process, queueing-theory

I'm a bit confused about this theorem about irreducible Markov Chains:

> If a Markov chain is irreducible, then all its states have the
> same period $d(i) := g.c.d.\{n > 0|P^n(i, i) > 0\}$.[[source]](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewlr/226F06/markov.pdf)

Let's suppose we have the following matrix which represents an irreducible Markov Chain:

\begin{equation}
P = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0.8 & 0.2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
if we start from state 1, we can reach it again after two transitions:
\begin{equation}
1\rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 1
\end{equation}
but if we start from state 2, we can only reach it again after 4 transitions:
\begin{equation}
2\rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 2
\end{equation}
So what is the period of the system? Is it 2 or 4? We can argue that it is 4 because 4 is a multiple of two and it is acceptable for both cases. But using the prementioned theorem $d(1) = 2$ and all other states should follow. What is it that I am getting wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

The period $\ d(i)\ $ of a state $\ i\ $ is not the *shortest* length of tine it takes to return to the state, but the gcd of *all* the times it can take to return to the state.  In your example, if you start from state $2$ you can reach it again after $\ 4,6,8,\dots\ $ steps.  That is $\ P^n(2,2)>0\ $ for any $\ n\ $ of the form $\ 4+2r\ $ where $\ r\ $ is any natural number.  The gcd of those return times is $2$.

Answer (score 3):

The period is $2$ as given in the formula.  A Markov chain is periodic if the chain can return to the same state only at multiples of some integer $>1$.  See https://www.randomservices.org/random/markov/Periodicity.html

Comment: Thank you. But the system cannot return to its first state after 2 transitions if it starts at state 2. Isn't this contradictory to the meaning of "period"?

Comment: Not in the way the term is used in Markov chains.  There's nothing that says the chain can return from every state to itself in the period, just in a *multiple* of the period.  It's not the same way "period" is used in discussion of periodic functions.

Comment: @saulspatz It's not unrelated to the way it's used for periodic functions though. For example if the chain has period $4$, then I can partition the state space into $4$ non-empty sets $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$, such that if I'm in set $A_i$ at time $t$, then I will also be in set $A_i$ at all times $t+4, t+8, t+12, \dots$. So if the chain has period $4$, then it has a projection which is a function with period $4$.